# Print data of a file stored in file pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, file-pointer

I have written content to a file using a file pointer. I would now like to print this data in the form of an array. I am new to programming in C, and it looks like printing file pointers is different.

Here is an example of my code,

```
int main(){

    double a=0;
    double b=0;
    double c=0;
    double d=0;

    int bufferLength = 330752;
    char buffer[bufferLength];

    FILE *fp = fopen("original.dat", "r");
    if (!fp){
        printf("Cant open the original file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *fp1 = fopen("24bitnoise.dat", "r");
    if (!fp1){
        printf("Cant open the noise file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *outfp= fopen("out.dat", "w");
    if(outfp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to create file\n");
    }
    while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {      
        if (2==sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a,&b)){  // Just printing col 2 //
            // printf("b: %f\n", b);
            fprintf(outfp, "%0.25f\n", b);
        }
    }

    FILE *noisefp= fopen("outnoise.dat", "w");
    if(noisefp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to create file\n");
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp1)) {     
        if (2==sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &c,&d)){  // Just printing col 2 //

            fprintf(noisefp, "%0.25f\n", d);
        }
    }
    printf("%f", outfp);
    printf("File transferred\n");
    fclose(outfp);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(noisefp);
    return 0;
}
```

I would now like to print the values from *outfp in the form of an array.

Comment: And what happens? Does it fail to compile? Does it misbehave? Please provide a [mre] of any code you want to discuss.

Comment: But `outfp` points to a file handle that is open for writing only. So what do you mean by 'values *from* `*outfp`'?

Comment: And the purpose of `fp1` is....?

Comment: Then save `a` and `b` into an array

Comment: So the out.dat file pointed to *outfp contains a column of float values. My intention is to put these values in an array so that I can add these values with another dat file stored in a file pointer.

I tried print("%f", outfp); 
The output I see is, 6955926286975695600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 which is not right.

Comment: Margi, " print this data in the form of an array." --> Please provide a sample desired output.

Comment: Margi "I tried `print("%f", outfp);`" implies you do not have all compiler warnings enabled.  Save time.  Enable them all.

Comment: `int bufferLength = 330752; char buffer[bufferLength];` is a _large_ buffer.  Try `int bufferLength = 100;
char buffer[bufferLength];`, something long enough for the longest _line_ of input.

Comment: I need to consider all the 330752 float values here because I'm going to convert this data file back to an audio file.

Comment: Margi, Is `original.dat` a text file (try opening with a text editor) or is it a binary file?  What format is it?  I suspect it is a [text file](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-dat-file-2620550)

Comment: Mrgi, `fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)` only reads a text _line_, not the whole file all at once.  A smaller buffer is better.

Comment: Chux, it's an audio .wav file that I have converted to dat file. It consists 2 columns of float values. I just need to print the values in out.dat into an array. 
This is out the out.dat file looks in rows,
0.0000001192092895499999900
0.0000001192092895499999900

Comment: Margi `printf("%f", outfp);` makes little sense.  What do you want this line of code to do?

Comment: I was hoping it would print all the values in the file out.dat. I also tried printf("%f", outfp[1]); to see if it'll print the values, but it's giving me the wrong value

Comment: Margi, 1) delete `printf("%f", outfp);`. 2) after closing the files: `outfp= fopen("out.dat", "r"); while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, outfp)) {    printf("%s", buffer);  }` to print the contents of "out.dat".

Comment: Chux, Thank you! That did print all the values in the file.  But this is in 'r' mode, so how can I put these values into an array?

Answer (score 0):

OP is attempting, incorrectly, to print the contents of a file with

```
printf("%f", outfp);
```

`"%f"` expects a matching `double`, not a `FILE *`.

---

To print the text contents of a file, line-by-line:

```
FILE *inf = fopen("out.dat", "r");
if (inf) {
  while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, inf)) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
  }
  fclose(inf);
}
```

---

> how can I put these values into an array?

The "trick" is how to determine the size of the array.

One simple approach:

```
size_t count = 0;
while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {      
  if (2==sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a,&b)) {
    count++;
  }
}

double fp_array = malloc(sizeof *fp_array * count);
if (fp_array == NULL) Handle_Out_of_memory();  // Some tbd code

// Read again
rewind(fp);
size_t i = 0;
while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {      
  if (2==sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a,&b)) {
    fp_array[i++] = b;
  }
}

// Use fp_array

free(fp_array);  // clean up when done.
```

A more elegant approach would re-size the allocation as needed and perform only one read pass.